# influxdb query basic percentage calculation

Tags: influxdb

I want calculate a division between a number of values different form zero in a specific table and the number of value equal to zero in the same table

```
SELECT (count("value") WHERE value = 0 / count("value") WHERE value != 0) * 100 FROM "ping_rtt" WHERE time < now() - 15
```

Obviously this is wrong and I was wondering what could me the correct way to structure the query.

Answer (score 3):

If your field `value` consists of just zeros or ones; you can easily calculate percentage as:

```
SELECT 100*sum(value)/count(value) from your_metric
```

Or simply use `Mean` function instead of `count/sum`.

But if `value` consists of any arbitrary numbers; there is a tricky way (based on this fact that current InfluxDB implementation calculates zero/zero as zero) to achieve this :) You can first map your field `value` to zeros and ones and then calculate percentage:

```
SELECT 100*count(map_value)/sum(map_value) FROM (SELECT value/value as map_value FROM your_metric)
```

It works properly in my influxdb 1.6.0; suppose there is a metric called `metric` which contain a field `val` as:

```
> select * from metric
name: metric
time                tag val
----                --- ---
1539780859073434500     15
1539780862064944400     10
1539780865272757400     7
1539780867449546100     0
1539780880145442700     -8
1539781131768616600 12  0
1539781644977103800 12  0.5
1539781649113051900 12  1.5
```

as you can see, there are different float number as 0,-8,1.5,0.5 and so on.
we can now map our `val` field to zero or one:

```
> select val/val as normal_val from metric
name: metric
time                normal_val
----                ----------
1539780859073434500 1
1539780862064944400 1
1539780865272757400 1
1539780867449546100 0
1539780880145442700 1
1539781131768616600 0
1539781644977103800 1
1539781649113051900 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Useful indeed. I' ll give a try :)

Comment: +1. If you have zeros and ones, then you can calculate 100*MEAN(map_value) directly - you will save one function and subquery. From the math point: value/value - there can be a division by zero, which is undefined.

Comment: The current implementation of InfluxDB calculates zero divide by zero as zero not NaN. Based on this fact the above answer is presented (as a tricky answer!) @JanGaraj